# How to apply custom halftone to ghostscript conversion of PDF file to bitmap

Tags: pdf, bitmap, ghostscript

I have a PDF file with a grayscale image that I'm trying to convert to monochromatic bitmap (1 bit per pixel) using ghostscript.  I can get everything to work fine, but I don't like the way the default grayscale conversion looks with coarse lines going through it.  My understanding is that I can customize the halftone algorithm to my liking, but I can't seem to get the postscript commands to have an effect on the output.  Am I using the 'sethalftone' command incorrectly? Is there a different approach I should consider?

```
gs -sDEVICE=bmpmono -sOutputFile=test.bmp -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -r300 -c "<< /HalftoneType 1 /Frequency 40 /Angle 0 /SpotFunction {pop}>> sethalftone" -sPageList=1 input.pdf
```

I can completely remove the "-c" command line parameter and it makes no difference.

This is what the current mono conversion looks like that I'm trying to improve upon:

[image: Sample]

Comment: For my current task, I'd rather have it be smaller specs, something more like this: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/dip/images/dither1.jpg

Comment: I think I'd be OK with the printer vector style if I can customize it and get them to be smaller dots

Comment: I need to stick with 300 dpi at the moment, so what I mean is skinnier lines and smaller dots (but 2x as many in the same space).  I presume this can be adjusted with the frequency and spot function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the default halftone built into Ghost Script has a limited working range and a tendency to provide an appearance leaning to one side, (it is deliberate design not accidental) there is a dither control but that tends to work effectively at r/20 to r/5 in this case showing -dDITHERPPI=25 to -dDITHERPPI=60 thus reducing the blocks in size. However there are other potential controls.

[image]

I am no expert on how these settings are best used (plagiarized) we would need to read the PS manual, or play with their values, but they seem to fare better.

[image]

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=bmpmono -r300 -o out.bmp -c "<< /Frequency 133 /Angle 45 /SuperCellSize 36 /Levels 255 >> .genordered /Default exch /Halftone defineresource { } settransfer 0.003 setsmoothness"  -f ../examples/text_graph_image_cmyk_rgb.pdf
```

***(note you may wish to include -dUseFastColor before -c "....)***

**Changing values**

/Angle common values may be 0 (0=GS default) 22 30 45 52 60 67 however `/Angle 45` is most common for this mono conversion, and variations coupled with a range of /Frequency (Line Screen Frequency ~= LPI) and  SuperCell size may produce unachievable or sub normal result.

/Frequency (75=GS default) can be set to different values but a common ratio is 4/3 = 133 (%) another is 170 however a rule of thumb is r/2 thus if your using 300dpi `/Frequency 150` may be better in this case.  The correct choice is down to a complex consideration of factors, so your grid at 45 degrees is spaced at sqrt(2)=1.41421356237 at an angle. Thus the horizontal & vertical effect is 0.7071....(in terms of page dpi) thus to match 300 dpi the LPI frequency needs to be possibly made relative so consider 212

/SuperCellSize eludes me Integer; default value = 1 -- actual cell size determined by Frequency, Angle, H/V Resolution. A larger value will allow more levels to be attained. Unclear as to what may be optimum without sample of target, so try a few values but some will trigger error feedback try around 32 or 64 as a reasonable max start point. note example uses 36 ?

> To prevent the undesirable moire patterns, Peter Fink proposed the Supercell Method named the Adobe Accurate Screen to realize the screen
> angle having RT with the required accuracy.3  The supercell designed in the image domain including m × m (m: integer) identical halftone cells is one solution to approximate accurately the required screen angle and screen ruling. https://www.imaging.org/site/PDFS/Papers/1998/PICS-0-43/668.pdf

You may also wish to try
/DotShape Integer; default value = 0 (CIRCLE). Other shapes available are:
1=REDBOOK, 2=INVERTED, 3=RHOMBOID, 4=LINE_X, 5=LINE_Y, 6=DIAMOND1, 7=DIAMOND2, 8=ROUNDSPOT,

These values and more can be found at https://ghostscript.com/doc/current/Language.htm

Upper Left is a mono area dithered in a graphics app where depending on resolution and density "worms" or "moire" patterns start to appear. To regulate such effects a deliberate screen is applied and at smallest units aberration's in the linework pattern will not be noticeable, unless zoomed beyond intended scrutiny.

```
gswin32c -sDEVICE=bmpmono -r300 -o out.bmp -c "<< /Frequency 106 /Angle 45 /SuperCellSize 64 /Levels 255 >> .genordered /Default exch /Halftone defineresource { } "  -f test.pdf
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

Imagemagick can use custom halftones, defined by XML files, so if you can't get the result you need directly with GhostScript, another option is to use GhostScript to output a high-resolution greyscale image, and use Imagemagick to produce the black and white halftoned image.